# Value in ngModel not updated in Angular input view

Tags: angularjs, input, formatting, angular-ngmodel, angular-template

I need to format the input values so I create a directive that use a template with ***require: 'ngModel'*** because I have to use ngModelController functions (*$parsers*, *$formatters*, etc.).

This is my HTML:

```
<div ng-model="myInputValue" amount-input-currency=""></div>
{{myInputValue}}
```

This is my directive:

```
.directive('amountInputCurrency', [function(){
        return {
            templateUrl: '../amountInputCurrency.tmpl.html',
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, model) {
        // ...
            }
       }
}
```

And this is my template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myInputValue">
```

The problem is that I can't updated the view after formatting the inserted value. For example if I write '*1*' I want change the value in this way:

```
model.$formatters.push(function(value) {
    return value + '00';
}
```

Alternative I try to set an event in this other way:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myInputValue" ng-blur="onBlur()">

scope.onBlur = function() {
    model.$viewValue = model.$viewValue + '00';
    // or model.$setViewValue(model.$viewValue + '00';);
    model.$render();
};
```

The *model.$viewValue* changes, *myInputValue* (in the HTML with *{{myInputValue}}*) changes but **not the value showed in the input box**... which is the problem? Thanks!

----------------**UPDATE**----------------

Probably the problem is because I have 2 ng-model (one in the HTML and one in the template): https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9296

How can I do? Both model refer to the same model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatters change how model values will appear in the view.

Parsers change how view values will be saved in the model.

```
 //format text going to user (model to view)
  ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
    return value.toUpperCase();
  });

  //format text from the user (view to model)
  ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
    return value.toLowerCase();
  });
```

Try using $parsers to change the view to your desired value.

I hope this will help you.

Update:

```
angular.module('components', []).directive('formatParse', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { model: "=ngModel" },
        template: '<input type="text" data-ng-model="model"></input><button type="button" data-ng-click="clickedView()">SetView</button><button type"button" data-ng-click="clickedModel()">SetModel</button>',
        link: function ($scope, el, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            format = "MMM Do, YYYY H:mm";
            console.log($scope.model);
            console.log(ngModelCtrl);

            $scope.clickedView = function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
            };

            $scope.clickedModel = function () {
                    $scope.model = 12; // Put here whatever you want
            };

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (date) {
                console.log("Parsing", date)
                return date; // Put here the value you want to be in $scope.model
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (date) {
                console.log("Formatting", date);
               console.log($scope.model);
               console.log(ngModelCtrl);
                return +date * 2; // Put here what you want to be displayed when clicking setView (This will be in ngModelCtrl.$viewValue)
            });
        }
    }   
});

angular.module('someapp', ['components']);
```

Try using this code and tell if this helped to get the result you wanted.

If it does I suggest, to console.log the ngModelCtrl that you way you will understand more about the inner flow of angular.

In addition, just so you have some more information,

When you edit the input in the view the formatters function are fired to change the model accordingly.

If the value that has been entered is not valid you can return in your formatters function the ngModelCtrl.$viewValue to keep $scope.model with his old and true information.

When you change your scope variable (in your case $scope.model) the parsers functions will be fired to change the view value. (You don't need to use $render, you just need to decide when you want to change your $scope.model),
I suggest instead of using $setViewValue put the value you want in your scope variable and the parsers will act accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried with $formatters but the new value that the function return it's not updated in the view (model.$viewValue has the old value), how can I do a model.$render(); after the return in the formatters? Thanks again

Comment: Hi thanks, now I have a problem with the viewValue, I create a new question with a plunker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537459/angular-model-viewvalue-not-showing-in-input-field